# How do I add a Python library dependency for a Lambda function in CodeBuild

Tags: aws-lambda, continuous-integration, python-3.8, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I have a CodePipline that grabs code out of CodeCommit bundles it up in CodeBuild and then publishes it via CloudFormation.

I want to use the Python package gspread and because it's not part of the standard AWS Linux image I need to install it.

Currently when the code is run I get the error:

- [ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'index': No module named 'gspread'

**Code structure**

```
- buildspec.yml
- template.yml
package/
  - gspread/
  - gspread-3.6.0.dist-info/
  - (37 other python packages)
source/
  - index.py
```

buildspec.yml -- EDITED

```
version: 0.2
phases:
  install:
    commands:
      # Use Install phase to install packages or any pre-reqs you may need throughout the build (e.g. dev deps, security checks, etc.)
      - echo "[Install phase]"
      - pip install --upgrade pip
      - pip install --upgrade aws-sam-cli
      - sam --version
      - cd source
      - ls
      - pip install --target . gspread oauth2client
      # consider using pipenv to install everything in the environement and then copy the files installed into the /source folder
      - ls
    runtime-versions:
        python: 3.8
  pre_build:
    commands:
      # Use Pre-Build phase to run tests, install any code deps or any other customization before build
      # - echo "[Pre-Build phase]"
  build:
    commands:
      - cd ..
      - sam build
      
  post_build:
    commands:
      # Use Post Build for notifications, git tags and any further customization after build
      - echo "[Post-Build phase]"      
      - export BUCKET=property-tax-invoice-publisher-deployment
      - sam package --template-file template.yml --s3-bucket $BUCKET --output-template-file outputtemplate.yml
      - echo "SAM packaging completed on `date`"

##################################
# Build Artifacts to be uploaded #
##################################
artifacts:
  files:
    - outputtemplate.yml
  discard-paths: yes

cache:
  paths:
  # List of path that CodeBuild will upload to S3 Bucket and use in subsequent runs to speed up Builds
    - '/root/.cache/pip'
```

The index.py file has more in it than this. But to show the offending line.

-- index.py --

```
import os
import boto3
import io
import sys
import csv
import json
import smtplib
import gspread #**<--- Right here**

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print("In lambda_handler")
```

**What I've tried**

- Creating the /package folder and committing the gspread and other packages
- Running "pip install gspread" in the CodeBuild builds: commands:

At the moment, I'm installing it everywhere and seeing what sticks. (nothing is currently sticking)

Version: Python 3.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may need to do the following steps :

1. Use virtual env to install the packages locally.
2. Create requirements.txt to let code build know of the package requirement.
3. In CodeBuild buildspec.xml , include commands to install virutal env and then supply requirements.txt.

   pre_build:
   commands:

   - pip install virtualenv
   - virtualenv env
   - . env/bin/activate
   - pip install -r requirements.txt

Detailed steps here for reference :

https://adrian.tengamnuay.me/programming/2018/07/01/continuous-deployment-with-aws-lambda/

Comment: Thanks for your response. Have you tried it with pipenv ? That seems to be the latest and favoured way of managing dependencies

Comment: Thanks for the information @dinakaran. The reference is old now, but still works. The root of my problem was that I wasn't copying the dependencies into the /source folder i.e. codeuri . Once I did that the 'sam build' and 'sam package' took care of the rest.

Comment: oh okay. glad to know you were able to figure out this @JiminyJames